# Why didn't Madara absorb this technique?

Tags: naruto

Madara has awakened Rinnegan in both eyes. He also has Senjutsu chakra and able to perform many high level technique. One of his technique is to be able absorb all ninjutsu/element. But I wonder why he cannot absorb Gai's Evening Elelphant technique. I knew it's stated in narutowiki that:
`

> The Evening Elephant is a high-level, forbidden **taijutsu** that can be
>   performed by those users who have opened all Eight Gates.
>
> This technique is a continuous assault of five punches, with each "foot" as they are referred to being performed faster than the one before. It creates a cannon of pressurised **air** which bears the appearance of an elephant's leg, causing devastating damage to the opponent.

Why didn't Madara just absorb the **air/wind** from the attack? If it's a direct hit from the fist Madara may not be able to absorb it.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been explained before, during the battle of Gai with Kisame.

Kisame's technique absorbs chakra from the Ninjutsu technique and grows stronger while the opposite attack grows weaker, but it couldn't do anything about the Sonic Punch, Hirodora (Afternoon Tiger). This is because unlike nature manipulation techniques Gai's Gate technique utilizes pure Taijutsu.

Rinnegan can absorb any and all Ninjutsu techniques, because Ninjutsu **uses Chakra to achieve nature manipulation**, whereas Gai's technique utilizes the speed achieved by the Gates to create the destructive power of his attack from the atmospheric air itself, and which can't be absorbed.

Also, it is stated in the Manga that Madara in ten-tails Jinchuriki form only Senjutsu and Taijutsu work since he can absorb all Ninjutsu.

Comment: How about flame thrower petrol? Can madara absorb the fire from it?

Comment: @Vahn Since Flamethrowers, Gasoline bombs etc. haven't been used it'd be speculating only. However, we have not seen any Rinnegane user absorb elements directly such as Rivers, Fire, or even the ground directly.

Answer (score 0):

The Rinnegan lets you absorb any ninjutsu technique.
For elemental ninjutsu, you can absorb the chakra of the attack, therefore nullifying it.
But since an air "cannon" isn't ninjutsu, there's nothing the rinnegan can do about it.

Comment: So Rinnegan absorb ninjutsu. Not nature element?

Comment: Absorbs chakra. Seen when Pain absorbs naruto's chakra directly from him.

Comment: How about flame thrower petrol? Can madara absorb the fire from it?